# Issues with TypeScript and TFS

Tags: typescript

There is probably a problem with TFS Visual Studio project conducted together with Typescript.

On build tsc can't overwrite the readonly .js file an throws Permission denied error.

```
Error   1   Permission denied   
Error   2   The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc 
"c:\users\schlicht\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\TypeScriptHTMLApp1\app.ts"" exited with code 1.
```

Is it possible **without** explicitly checking out the files to use a build **with** tsc?

Comment: FYI the latest version of Visual Studio 2013 with update 3 has fixed this problem. I have a project where the .js file is under TFS source control, nested under the .ts file. If you save the .ts file (causing a compile) the .js file is auto-checked out and updated.

Answer (score 6):

Don't check in the .js file. We use this approach on our TypeScript project and it works well. There is no need to have the generated .js in source control; think of the .js files as project output, like a .exe or .dll.

Comment: The issue with this is that the .js file then does not get generated in the production site on build...

Comment: This won't work. The .js files will not be deployed if you do, and also, they cannot be put into embedded resources if you exclude them. Use the attrib solution instead.

Answer (score 5):

Now,  if your build server is configured for the Typescript run, TSC will run and generate the JavaScript files.

Here is another alternative solution, in case you don’t want to remove the JS file. Because, if you remove the JS for time being, and any other developer check in those file again into TFS, the same error will come occur. (more over those are hidden files, so if you don’t check-in carefully, they can be checked-in in TFS)

In this case,  you can run a Pre-Build event, that will remove all read-only attributes  of the JS files for that project.

1. *Right Click* on the *Project* and Open the *Project Property Window*

2. Select the *Build Event* Tab

[image]

This will ensure, all the JS file release the Read-Only attributes and there will not be any error for write to file failed.

Hope this helps.

Source : http://dailydotnettips.com/2014/05/03/typescript-emit-error-write-to-file-failed-how-to-resolve

Comment: i added `attrib -r /s "$(ProjectDir)*.js.map"` also

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround: To keep your JS files as part of the project and in source control.

Use a Local Workspace, as this does not apply the read-only flag on files, so saving the .JS files do not require a check-out for it to be written to.

I found this because I was not exhibiting this problem, but others in my team were, so after some digging I found out what was different. I was using a Local Workspace instead of a Server Workspace.

The other team members have converted to a Local Workspace and they are smooth sailing once again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug (or missing feature) :

http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/108

Comment: Thanks, I had already thought of something. Using Web Essentials 2012 offers the possibility to compile automatically a TypeScript file (.ts) when is saved in Visual Studio. It also has a preview function. [link] http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Answer (score 0):

I [experienced](http://devio.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/typescript-projects-in-tfs/) this yesterday.

As iano stated, do not add the generated .js to TFS; or add `tf checkout` and `tf checkin` to the BeforeBuild target.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to people suggesting exclusion of .js files from the project, I have to say that this can only work in small and single solution software. In a big software application i.e. an ERP, there usually exists multiple solutions per module, and when each have .js files for themselves, delivering .js and other source files of this kind is usually made by making them "Embedded Resources" and some custom virtual path provider or something.

So, what works?
[This solution](http://dailydotnettips.com/2014/05/03/typescript-emit-error-write-to-file-failed-how-to-resolve/) might help you, I suggest you try it.

But anyways, as A. M. mentioned. this is a known bug. And I think the best solution for TypeScript compiler would be to skip writing .js files for those .ts files that are read-only (checked-in) themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: 
If you add the generated *.js files to TFS, then TFS write-protects them, if you check them in, or don't check them out. So if you change the *.ts file, it cannot generate the *.js file, because the file is write-protected. 
==> Error 
But if you don't check them in, the *.js file will be missing if you run deploy.  
==> Compiles, but Runtime error 
Also, if you need it as an embedded resource, you cannot exclude the file...

Additional problem 1: 
If you run "Rebuild Solution", Visual Studio wants to delete the *.js files generated by TypeScript, before it executes build. 
But deleting is not possible, because the *.js files are write-protected... 

==> Error

**Additional problem 2:** 
Since clean is not "Build", the pre-build events are not executed on clean... 
So if you remove the write-protection on pre-build, it will work if you do "build", but it will fail if you choose "Rebuild", irrespective of whether you do it in the solution or in the project.

Additional problem 3:
You cannot define a pre-clean event command in the project-settings editor.

So, here's what you can do: 
Run `attrib -r /s` (removes write protection) on your typescripted *.js files as pre-build action. 
e.g.

```
attrib -r /s "$(ProjectDir)Resources/Scripts/0/*.js"
```

This works, because * is expanded:

- If the file doesn't exist, there is no error, because no command is
  executed.
- If the file does exist, there is no error, the command is
  executed.

If you'd run it on a filename, it would fail if the file doesn't exist.

Now, you need to edit the project file (*.csproj) by hand, to add a pre-clean action.
The pre-clean action is the same as the pre-build action.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeClean">
    <!-- DO YOUR STUFF HERE -->
    <Exec Command="attrib -r /s &quot;$(ProjectDir)Resources/Scripts/0/*.js&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

And there you go. 
Now you can check the *.js files in, can edit the *.ts file (you'll need to unprotect the *.js file, or run build afterwards)

If you want to run it on a per file basis, the command is:

```
if EXIST "$(ProjectDir)Resources/Scripts/0/leaflet.EasyAjax.js" (
attrib -r "$(ProjectDir)Resources/Scripts/0/leaflet.EasyAjax.js"
)
```

or in XML-form:

```
<Exec Command="if EXIST &quot;$(ProjectDir)Resources/Scripts/0/leaflet.EasyAjax.js&quot; (&#xD;&#xA;attrib -r &quot;$(ProjectDir)Resources/Scripts/0/leaflet.EasyAjax.js&quot;&#xD;&#xA;)" />
```

And instead of removing the read-only attribute wholesale in the pre-build action, you can also check the individual files out with the TFS command-line tool: 
`"$(DevEnvDir)CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/tf.exe" checkout /lock:none "$(ProjectDir)Resources/Scripts/0/leaflet.EasyAjax.js"`

By the way, you can find a list of VisualStudio/MsBuild macros here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2017

And to find out the actual value of the macro:

- right click on your project in the Solution Explorer, select *Properties*
- select the *Build Events* tab
- click the *Edit pre-build* or *Edit post-build* button, either is fine
- in the window that pops up, click the *Macros* button
- scroll down the list till you find `ProjectDir`, in the next pane is its actual value

Also, instead of using the pre-build event in the project, you can add the checkout as BeforeBuild-target command. That way nobody can accidentially remove it if they put something into pre-build in project-settings.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(DevEnvDir)CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/tf.exe&quot; checkout /lock:none &quot;$(ProjectDir)Resources/Scripts/0/leaflet.EasyAjax.js&quot;" />
  </Target>
```